# Compiling templates every time I use them

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js

I'm using Backbone, Requirejs and Handlebars to manage my front-end structure. However I've run into a bump. Consider the following snippet:

```
render: function() {

    var template = Handlebars.compile(TestViewTemplate);
    var srchtml = template({
        test: 'hello'
    });

    this.$el.html(srchtml); 
}
```

Lets say this view is rendered multiple times in the website, executing the render function multiple times. Will calling the .compile method cause overhead as the view needs to be "recompiled" every time or does Handlebars save a cached copy of the template every time one is compiled? Should I pass around a Context object to all my View modules where I save the compiled templates and check if the template has already been compiled and if so, use the already compiled one and render that?

Is there a standard way to deal with this?

I'm really fresh with Handlebars, any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: An article for you that even includes code for a caching implementation: [JavaScript Performance: Pre-Compiling And Caching HTML Templates](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/10/javascript-performance-pre-compiling-and-caching-html-templates/)

Comment: u can also checkout MarionetteJS approach - Renderer object and TemplateCache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have come to a more persistent solution and would like to share the way I did it with others.

I created a Context object which is only instantiated once and passed around throughout the application. This is how it looks:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'handlebars'
], function($, Handlebars) {

    this.ctx = this.ctx || new function(options) {
        if( typeof options === 'undefined' ) options = {};

        /**
         * introducing a _this variable that holds scope to the base object.
         */
        var _this = this;

        /**
         * Keeps track of whether the Context has been initialized or not,
         * prevents double initialization.
         */
        var initialized = false;

        var initHelpers = function() {
            Handlebars.registerHelper('ifeq', function(v1, v2, options) {
                return (v1 === v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
            });
        }

        this.init = function(options) {

            if( initialized ) {
                console.log('Prevented an attempt at initializing the Context object twice.');
                return;
            }

            /* Setting the debug variable, look at the declaration above in the implementation
             * for more information about this. */
            debug = options.debug || false;

            /**
             * Initializing the Handlebars helpers, necessary for the template rendering.
             */
            initHelpers();
        }

        // Functionality for the template caching methods. //

        var hbsTemplates = {};

        this.getTemplate = function(name, templateHtml) {
            return hbsTemplates[name] || function() {
                var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(templateHtml);
                hbsTemplates[name] = compiledTemplate;
                return compiledTemplate;
            }();
        }
    }
    return this.ctx;
});
```

We also have to initiate it, preferably as soon as possible.

```
Context.init({
    /* Options */
});
```

When I create a Backbone View I declare the following variable:

```
template: Context.getTemplate('mywidget.mytemplate', FloorViewTemplate),
```

Notice the string that is passed as the first parameter. This is used to reference the template in the HashMap in the Context object, I denote this by the folder structure. In this case it is mywidget/mytemplate.hbs denoted as mywidget.mytemplate

Remember at this point the Context object has been fetched as any other type

```
define([
    'Context'
], function(Context) {

});
```

Finally, we get the template and supply our parameters.

```
var html = this.template({
    arg1: 1,
    arg2: 2
});
```

Now it's just a matter of adding the html to the DOM.

This works fine. If anybody has any other ideas as how to do this more efficient please edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the full answer you were looking for but its a bit too much for a comment - 
Although not completely removing the overhead my normal approach when creating a view is to declare a property template which is the compiled template. This way it will only compile when being created.

```
var ModelView = Backbone.View.extend({

    //get the template and cache it for future use
    template: Handlebars.compile(templateName),
    initialize: function() {
    },

    //render this view with the models data
    render: function() {
        //attach the generated template to this views $el
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },


});
```

When re-rendering the same view it already has a reference to the compiled template. But this doesn't get over the fact every new view of this type will be compiling

Comment: Thanks for your input, this is essentially what I have gone for but I'm yet to find a way of caching the templates. I will come back to this thread once I have found a more persistent solution.

Comment: as suggested by @Evgeniy marionette has this feature and even if you don't use all that marionette has to offer it provides a great structure for views and nested views